# help with t-sql self join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, self-join

Based on the following table

```
ID  Date         State 
-----------------------------
1   06/10/2010   Complete
1   06/04/2010   Pending
2   06/06/2010   Active   
2   06/05/2010   Pending
```

I want the following ouptut

```
ID  Date         State 
---------------------------
1   06/04/2010   Complete
2   06/05/2010   Active
```

So date is the earliest one and State is the latest one. I am failing to apply self join on the table to get the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         MIN(t.date),
         (SELECT TOP 1
                 x.state
            FROM TABLE x
           WHERE x.id = t.id
        ORDER BY x.date DESC)
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: thanks omg ponies. But this is not giving the correct State. It is giving Pending for both rows.

Comment: You need an DESC on your ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, min(Date) Date, (select State 
                              from tbl
                             where ID = t.ID and
                                   Date = (select max(Date) 
                                             from tbl
                                            where ID = t.ID)) State
  from tbl t
 group by ID
```

Comment: @Khorkrak: this is giving 4 rows as output.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it in MySQL - retry it without the State in the group by - works in MySQL now.  As for SQL Server, if it gives you a problem try just surrounding the State expression with some aggregate function like Max()

Comment: Cool and tada no need from non-standard SQL extensions either such as TOP ;-)

Comment: TOP is ANSI ;)  I'll vote for you if you rework the query to not use a subselect

Comment: Is doing a sort for every row faster than doing a max or equivalent?  What's the plan look like in SQL Server since they have a decent explain plan there as opposed to the piece of crap we're stuck with in MySQL...

Comment: TOP is not ANSI it's just the Microsoft way - the 2003 ANSI standard is quite different - here's a page that compares the variations [TOP N / Limit N](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-top-n-standard)